# Extract data from JSON file using jupyter

Tags: python, json, jupyter

I m facing a problem at extracting some data from JSON, I did the same with HTML

```
user_utterance =[]
for i in  data.find_all("div", {"class": "response"} ):
        user_utterance.append(i)
```

but its not working, so my question is how can I do the same with json file?

my code so far:

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\file.json', "r" ,encoding='UTF-8')
data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Please share the JSON you're looking to parse.

Comment: it is something like this {
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "welcoming",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "hi"
       
      ],
      "description": ""
    },{
      "type": "standard",
      "title": "pay",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "text": "To view the benefits and requirements, please visit:"
              }
            "response_type": "text",
          
          }

Comment: Your JSON structure is **not** well formatted.

Comment: well the file is very big but i used json.load() and the outcome is dictionary {'intents': [{'intent': 'welcoming',
   'examples': [{'text': 'hi'},
    {'text': 'i have a question'},
    {'text': 'hello'},
    {'text': 'yes'},
   'description': ''},
  {'intent': 'PAY',
   'examples': [{ and so one }]

Comment: Please share the whole JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON decoder performs the translations given [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder).

The python data structure that it returns looks very much like the original JSON. The outermost structure will probably be a `dict` or `list`.

Without knowing how your JSON file looks like it is hard to give a more concrete answer.
The partial example that you have shown is not valid JSON; the "[" and "{" are not well balanced.

Comment: my file looks like this: {
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "welcoming",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "hi"
       
      ],
      "description": ""
    },{
      "type": "standard",
      "title": "pay",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "text": "To view the benefits and requirements, please visit:"
              }
            "response_type": "text",
          
          }
        and i want to extract some values from it